# Conditional str_remove based on data frame column

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe (pasted below), in which I am trying to set to blank the value of one column based on the value of another column. The idea is that if `X6` equals `Nbre CV` or if `X6`equals `Nbre BVD` then I want `X6`for that row to be blank.

Unfortunately using the following code the entire X6 column turns to NA or missing.

```
extractstack <- extractstack %>%
  mutate(across(everything(), as.character) %>%
        mutate(X6 = if_else(X6 == `Nbre CV`, str_remove(X6, `Nbre CV`), X6)) %>%
        mutate(X6 = if_else(X6 == `Nbre CV`, str_remove(X6, `Nbre BVD`), X6)))
```

```
structure(list(X1 = c("", "", "40", "", "", "41", "", "", "42", 
"", "", "43", "", "", "44", ""), X2 = c("", "", "EP. KAPALA", 
"", "", "INST. MOTULE", "", "", "CABANE BABOA", "", "", "CABANE BANANGI", 
"", "", "E.P.BINZI", ""), X3 = c("", "", "MOBATI-BOYELE", "", 
"", "MOBATI-BOYELE", "", "", "MOBATI-BOYELE", "", "", "AVURU-GATANGA", 
"", "", "AVURU-GATANGA", ""), X4 = c("", "", "BOGBASA", "", "", 
"BOSOBEA", "", "", "BOSOBEA", "", "", "BANANGI", "", "", "GURUZA", 
""), X5 = c("", "", "", "", "", "MOBENGE", "", "", "BABOA", "", 
"", "DIFONGO", "", "", "DULIA", ""), X6 = c("", "", "BOGBASA", 
"", "", "", "1", "", "", "1", "", "", "1", "", "", "1"), X7 = c("1", 
"", "", "1", "", "", "4", "", "", "1", "", "", "1", "", "", "5"
), X8 = c("2", "", "", "2", "", "", "510 110", "", "", "510 111", 
"", "", "510 112", "", "", "510 113"), X9 = c("510 108", "", 
"", "510 109", "", "", "A - D", "", "", "A", "", "", "A", "", 
"", "A - E"), page = c("4", "4", "4", "4", "5", "5", "5", "5", 
"5", "5", "5", "5", "5", "5", "5", "5"), Plage = c("A - B", NA, 
NA, "A - B", NA, NA, "A - D", NA, NA, "A", NA, NA, "A", NA, NA, 
"A - E"), `Code SV` = c("510 108", NA, NA, "510 109", NA, NA, 
"510 110", NA, NA, "510 111", NA, NA, "510 112", NA, NA, "510 113"
), `Nbre BVD` = c("2", NA, NA, "2", NA, NA, "4", NA, NA, "1", 
NA, NA, "1", NA, NA, "5"), `Nbre CV` = c("1", NA, NA, "1", NA, 
NA, "1", NA, NA, "1", NA, NA, "1", NA, NA, "1")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-16L))
```

Comment: Most of your `X6` column is `NA`. What should happen then? And what do you mean with _blank_? An `NA`-value or an empty string`""`?

Comment: Hi @MartinGal, I mean an empty string "". If X6 is NA I want it to stay as it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's basically Chris Ruehlemann's answer (I don't know why he removed it, I would remove this one for the original one):

```r
library(dplyr)

extractstack %>%
  mutate(across(everything(), as.character),
         X6 = coalesce(ifelse(X6 == `Nbre BVD` | X6 == `Nbre CV`, "", X6), X6))
```

compares `X6` with the columns `Nbre BVD` and `Nbre CV`. If there is matching content, `X6` will be changed to an empty string `""`, else `X6` stays unchanged. But for your given data, this code doesn't replace anything, since there are simply no matches in `X6` with `Nbre BVD` and `Nbre CV` besides `NA`-values.

Comment: thank you for this. I changed the dataframe extract in my question, now you can see that sometimes `Nbre CV` and X6 are the same. If I run your code, everything in X6 changes to NA including this one word `BOGBASA` which should stay here.

Comment: I made a small adjustement... Please try it out.